# Java exception - block overrun

Tags: java, tensorflow, ioexception

While running `TensorFlow` build with Adopt `OpenJDK 8`, I am facing below build failure intermittently:

```
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: no such package '@nasm//': java.io.IOException: block overrun
```

I tried building with various values of `-xmx` and `-xms` as well as setting `--jobs` for `Bazel`, but still facing the issue.

Any pointers in resolving this would be helpful.

Comment: Could it be related to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16862 ?

Comment: Does the exception not have a stack trace?

Comment: Strange that the issue is seen intermittently and on 1 machine, whereas similar setup on other machine gives server crash error. 
The exception is not showing any stack trace.
Is it more related to Java memory settings?

Comment: My guess is that downloading, uncompressing, and verifying the `nasm` package is failing for some reason.

Comment: I could download `nasm` using wget, so no network issue. Also added `https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.12.02/nasm-2.12.02.tar.bz2` in URLs(workspace.bzl) as mentioned in the issue but still facing same error during build!

Comment: The build works with openjdk-8 however fails with Adopt Openjdk 8.
Any idea how to resolve this JVM error?